# MockProvider could not find client in the context

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

I am using MockProvider to test my components with Apollo queries. I have wrapped it this way

```
import { MockedProvider } from '@apollo/client/testing';

<MockedProvider mocks={mocks}>
    <MyWrapper>{children}</MyWrapper>
  </MockedProvider>
```

But I still get the error while running my unit tests:

```
Invariant Violation: Could not find "client" in the context or passed in as an option. Wrap the root component in an <ApolloProvider>, or pass an ApolloClient instance in via options.
```

Here are my dependencies:

```
"@apollo/client": "^3.6.9",
"react": "^17.0.0",
```

Would really appreciate some help. Thank you

Comment: Can you add to your post the code of `MyWrapper`